# Import Azure key vault certificate to app service using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have created a azure key vault and uploaded a certificate. Now I want to import the certificate into Azure app service using PowerShell. Most of the scripts I have looked suggests to download it in local and then to upload. Since I'm planning to put the script in pipeline. I can't do it.

Is there any PowerShell command to import key vault certificate into Azure app service directly.

Examples I seen :

New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName ppldemosslkeypipeline
-ResourceGroupName keyappservice_pipeline
-Name ppldemosslkeypipeline
-CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $pfxPassword -SslState SniEnabled

Instead of providing the certifcate file path is there any way i can provide key vault certifcate place holder using azure keyvault url.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a 2 step process:

1. You will need to import the certificate stored into your Azure Key Vault into your App Service. You can use [`Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/import-azwebappkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-6.0.0) Cmdlet to do so.
2. Bind this certificate to your App Service. You can use [`New-AzWebAppSSLBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebappsslbinding?view=azps-6.0.0) by specifying the certificate thumbprint for that purpose.

Comment: Whether the import-azwebappkeyvaultcertificate works in psversion 5.1.19041.906 Because when i run the command I get 'Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: I looked up the documentation for version 6.0.0.0.

Comment: I resolved the not recognized by installing the module az.websites But I face the below error
 Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
when I run the cmd

Comment: Added the screen shot for more information

Comment: It's a permission issue based on the screenshot. Please try by granting appropriate permissions.