# Enable Keyvault certificate to existing Azure app services automatically

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am looking for a automated solution to link Azure Key vault to Existed App/FunctionApps.

**Steps followed**

1. i understood, we have to enable **system identity = true** for all the resource as a prerequisite.
2. create Access policy in azure Keyvault for the App/function app and provide access to Certificate.
3. Finally, import the keyvault certificate to Azure appservice.  whole process can be done manually.  but i am looking for automated solution using powershell, Azure automation or terraform script.

Comment: It sounds like you need to hire someone to write some code for you but first you'll neeed to decide if it is to be done in Powershell or Terraform as these are very different approaches.

Comment: I am good at writing terraform script, but I couldn't find the straight approach to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Generally this site works by you showing what you tried, explaining the error or issue, then people try and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to set the access policy for a Web APP after satisfying the prerequisite i.e. `System Assigned = true` :

```
Connect-AzAccount
$subscription = "yoursubID"
$appname = "testansumanapp"
$rg = "rgname"
$vaultname = "Keyvaultansumantest01"
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $appname
$keyvault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $vaultname -ResourceGroupName $rg
$newaccesspolicy= Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultname -ObjectId $webapp.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToSecrets all -PermissionsToCertificates all -PermissionsToKeys all
$webappconfig= az webapp config set -g $rg -n $appname --vnet-route-all-enabled true
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

---

And to Import SSL certificate from Keyvault to Web App, You can refer [Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/import-azwebappkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-6.4.0) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887948/import-azure-key-vault-certificate-to-app-service-using-powershell).